# Displaying the path for Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: java

Whats up guys, I have a question regarding the Dijkstra algorithm. I have made it so that a user enter a graph file, and then the user enters the source node and destination node. And my code so far calculates the shortest distance between them, like it's supposed to. However I do not know to print the path of nodes it goes through in order to get to the destination node. Please help this is a homework assignment due today. Here is my code:

```
package minheap;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MinHeap {


private int veNum;
private int x;
private int y;
private Vertex[] vertices;
private int size;



public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("%%%%%%Enter the name of the file that contains the graph");
    String file = input.nextLine();

    MinHeap minHeap = new MinHeap(file);
    System.out.println("What city would you like to start from?(Please enter a number "
            + "from 0 to 87574)");
    int start = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("What city would you like to get to?(Please enter a number "
            + "from 0 to 87574)");
    int end = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

    minHeap.findShortestPaths(start, end);

}



    public MinHeap(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(file));
    String sizeString = input.next();       //get the size as a string
    size = Integer.parseInt(sizeString);

    System.out.println("======The size is: " + size);
    vertices = new Vertex[size];
   // addNodes();

    input.next();

    /*Now read the vertices*/
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++){


        veNum = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        x = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        y = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

        vertices[i] = new Vertex(veNum, x, y);

    }


    /*Now read the edges */
    while(input.hasNext()){


        int vertex1 = indexForName(input.next());
        int vertex2 = indexForName(input.next());

        //System.out.println("====" + vertex1 + "====" + vertex2);

        /*Formula to calculate the distance(weight)*/
        int distance = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vertices[vertex1].xCord - vertices[vertex2].xCord, 2) 
                + Math.pow(vertices[vertex1].yCord - vertices[vertex2].yCord, 2));



        /*Pass the 2 vertexes that make an edge, and their distance to addEdge method*/
        addEdge(vertex1, vertex2, distance);  

        /*System.out.println("X cord: " + vertices[vertex1].xCord + "|  Y cord: " + vertices[vertex1].yCord + 
                "|  X cord2: " + vertices[vertex2].xCord + "|  Y cord2: " + vertices[vertex2].yCord);
        */

    }
    }


    //======================================================================================================
 int indexForName(String name){

    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++){
    /*Look for the vertex name in the array to see if they match with the one the one from
    the file */
        if(vertices[i].name == Integer.parseInt(name)){

            return i;
        }

    }

    return -1;


}

 //===============================================================================================================


    public void addEdge(int sourceName, int destinationName, int weight) {
        int srcIndex = sourceName;
        int destiIndex = destinationName;
        vertices[srcIndex].adj = new Neighbour(destiIndex, weight, vertices[srcIndex].adj);
        vertices[destiIndex].indegree++;
    }

    public void findShortestPaths(int sourceName, int end){


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (vertices[i].name == sourceName) {
                applyDikjstraAlgorith(vertices[i], vertices[end]);
                break;// in this case we need not traverse the nodes which are
                // not reachable from the source Node
            }
        }
        //applyDikjstraAlgorith(vertices[sourceName], vertices[end]);
        // for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        //   System.out.println("Distance of "+vertices[i].name+" from Source: "+ vertices[i].cost);
        //}
    }

    public class Vertex {
        int cost;
        int name;
        Neighbour adj;
        int indegree;
        State state;
        int xCord;
        int yCord;

        public Vertex(int name, int xCord, int yCord) {
            this.name = name;
            cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            state = State.NEW;
            this.xCord = xCord;
            this.yCord = yCord;


        }

        public int compareTo(Vertex v) {
            if (this.cost == v.cost) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (this.cost < v.cost) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public enum State {
        NEW, IN_Q, VISITED
    }

    public class Neighbour {
        int index;
        Neighbour next;
        int weight;

        Neighbour(int index, int weight, Neighbour next) {
            this.index = index;
            this.next = next;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    public void applyDikjstraAlgorith(Vertex src, Vertex end) {


        Heap heap = new Heap(size);
        heap.add(src);
        src.state = State.IN_Q;
        src.cost = 0;
        while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex u = heap.remove();
            u.state = State.VISITED;
            Neighbour temp = u.adj;    //the neighbor of the vertex being removed. it accesses it adj neighbor list
            System.out.println("=======Edge weights");
            while (temp != null) {    //while it has a neighbor
                if (vertices[temp.index].state == State.NEW) {  //if that neighbor is unvisited
                    heap.add(vertices[temp.index]);             //add the unvisited vertices to the heap
                    vertices[temp.index].state = State.IN_Q;    //make the state indicating its in the heap
                }
                System.out.println("Weight from "+ vertices[u.name].name + " to " + vertices[temp.index].name +" is "+ temp.weight);
                if (vertices[temp.index].cost > u.cost + temp.weight) {  //if the neighbors weight is less than
                    vertices[temp.index].cost = u.cost + temp.weight;


                    heap.heapifyUP(vertices[temp.index]);



                }
                temp = temp.next;

            }
        }

        System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The shortest distance from "+src.name +" to "+end.name+" is " 
                    + end.cost);

    }

    public static class Heap {
        private Vertex[] heap;
        private int maxSize;
        private int size; //starts off as 0


        public Heap(int maxSize) {
            this.maxSize = maxSize;
            heap = new Vertex[maxSize];  //make the max size for the heap array made of vertices 

        }

        public void add(Vertex u) {

            heap[size++] = u;       //fill the heap array with the vertices, starting at position 0
            //
            heapifyUP(size - 1);      //pass each vertext ino heapifyUP (vertex type)
        }

        public void heapifyUP(Vertex u) {
            for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {  //look for vertex in the heap array 
                if (u == heap[i]) { 

                    heapifyUP(i);  //if its found, go to heapifyUp method (int type) and pass in the vertex num
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void heapifyUP(int position) {

            int currentIndex = position;
            Vertex currentItem = heap[currentIndex];

            int parentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) / 2;
            Vertex parentItem = heap[parentIndex];





            while (currentItem.compareTo(parentItem) == -1) {
                swap(currentIndex, parentIndex);
                currentIndex = parentIndex;

                if (currentIndex == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
                parentIndex = (currentIndex - 1) / 2;
                parentItem = heap[parentIndex];


            }
        }

        public Vertex remove() {
            Vertex v = heap[0];
            swap(0, size - 1);
            heap[size - 1] = null;
            size--;
            heapifyDown(0);
            return v;
        }

        public void heapifyDown(int postion) {
            if (size == 1) {
                return;
            }

            int currentIndex = postion;
            Vertex currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
            int leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
            int rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;
            int childIndex;
            if (heap[leftChildIndex] == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (heap[rightChildIndex] == null) {
                childIndex = leftChildIndex;
            } else if (heap[rightChildIndex].compareTo(heap[leftChildIndex]) == -1) {
                childIndex = rightChildIndex;
            } else {
                childIndex = leftChildIndex;
            }
            Vertex childItem = heap[childIndex];
            while (currentItem.compareTo(childItem) == 1) {
                swap(currentIndex, childIndex);
                currentIndex = childIndex;
                currentItem = heap[currentIndex];
                leftChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 1;
                rightChildIndex = 2 * currentIndex + 2;
                if (heap[leftChildIndex] == null) {
                    return;
                }
                if (heap[rightChildIndex] == null) {
                    childIndex = leftChildIndex;
                } else if (heap[rightChildIndex].compareTo(heap[leftChildIndex]) == -1) {
                    childIndex = rightChildIndex;

                } else {
                    childIndex = leftChildIndex;
                }

            }

        }

        public void swap(int index1, int index2) {
            Vertex temp = heap[index1];
            heap[index1] = heap[index2];
            heap[index2] = temp;


        }

        public boolean isEmpty() {

            return size == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The sample.txt file is as follows:

```
6 9

0 1000 2400

1 2800 3000

2 2400 2500

3 4000 0

4 4500 3800

5 6000 1500

0 1

0 3

1 2

1 4

2 4

2 3

2 5

3 5
```

Again, the actual algorithm works, I just need help printing the path. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: in each vertex add a field to remember the predecessor in the shortest path that led to this vertex.

Comment: Yea I did do that, but I don't know where exactly to place the instructions to store the predecessor.

Comment: You would do that, whenever the cost gets updated. That's when you have found a better path to this particular vertex.

Comment: Yea that is what I do, in my code I do:  vertices[temp.index].previous = vertices[u.name]; when it finds a lower weight on an edge, then I make a for loop to print out the previous nodes where it is not null, and it doesn't print out the right ones. Can you correct me on what I am doing wrong in terms of code